# MFC Dialog Combo Box in a List Control

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, clistctrl

I'm trying to create a dialog window with a List Control (report view) that displays a column of text. I'm trying to add another column that displays a combo box that will hold a list of possible actions for the first column. Is there any easy way to do this in MFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with something like CListCtrl (or not without a lot of owner drawn code). Instead have a look at a 3rd party control like [CGridListCtrlEx](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29064/CGridListCtrlEx-Grid-Control-Based-on-CListCtrl) which will do all the heavy lifting for you.